# Is there an free alternative to MAMP PRO?

Tags: php, macos, netbeans, mamp

NetBeans is recommending to use MAMP for Apache + MySQL + PHP on the Mac. There's a MAMP and a MAMP PRO. The MAMP is actually nothing more than a collection of open source libraries and stuff like PHP, MySQL, etc. in one big directory that goes to /Application/MAMP/. It comes with a little GUI to start/stop the server and to do some very basic settings. However, it is extremely limited. There's a MAMP PRO which does some more things but costs like $65. As I'm not making any money with my web dev I look for free solutions.

So is there something else that's open source / free, which does the same thing like MAMP Pro? starting / stopping PHP / Apache / MySQL on the Mac, configuring hosts, ports, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there something wrong with the software already built-in?

The official MySQL distro includes a graphical start/stop client.  It's a single button, in fact.

The built-in copy of Apache can be startted and stopped in the file sharing settings area.  Combine it with a [not-ancient version of PHP](http://www.entropy.ch/software/macosx/php/) and you're set.

Comment: well, the thing about MAMP PRO is, that it lets you easily configure hosts and stuff like that. But you're right, actually all the stuff is there already. But that's not the point.

Comment: @Charles: One advantage of using MAMP is that it allows you to move your complete setup (files, databases, configurations, etc.) around easily because everything is stored within the MAMP application folder. If you need to switch to a different computer, you can simply drag the MAMP folder across and continue working.

Comment: Just thought I'd add something here. I looked at this post when it was posted back in 2009. As it stands I'm still using MAMP. there was an alternative 'controller' program that allowed you to manage your MAMP or XAMPP service on the mac, and add virtual hosts. It is called VirtualHostX. Personally I didnt like it but may be worth looking into.

Answer (score 17):

Learn how to edit the Apache config file, then you can do anything you want. All you'll need is a text editor. I have MAMP free and just edit my config file as necessary. My Apache config for MAMP is located at /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf. The file is well commented and you can Google any of the settings in there to learn more about them. GUI tools are a nice luxury, but we shouldn't be completely dependent upon them.

Answer (score 6):

One of the problems with using the built in packages of Apache etc is that they considered system software and are routinely updated by apple's software update. Most of the time this is fine, But sometime if you have a lot of custom tweaks or version updates or want to use a very specific version you can sometimes get tripped up by the software update. So that is one argument for alternative package like MAMP which can be more precisely managed like a production evironment.

Plus if one is "learning" apache and PHP administration it is less risk to bork an standalone package like MAMP or Macports.

As for alternatives to MAMP, macports it useful. But also there is the Bitnami project

http://bitnami.org/

They have nice installers for specific application bundles, and a vanilla LAMP type environments. There is also a clean uninstaller which is nice. So experiment away and you don't have to worry about break system software or configurations.

Comment: We also recently bundled a small GUI utility to start/stop services

Comment: +1 For Bitnami. Particularly if you are just after one app, such as Joomla or Wordpress. I'm happy editing apache config on my server but on my home PC it's nice to have it all done for you in a ready to use app.

Comment: This is Daniel from BitNami here. Just wanted to let you know we have now also a version of MAMP in the Mac OS X app store (completely free, as our other stacks) https://itunes.apple.com/app/mamp-stack/id571310406

Answer (score 2):

You can always use a package manager like [MacPorts](http://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/MAMP) or [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Installation) and follow their guides to getting set up.

Answer (score 2):

<s>There is a solid, open source, alternative to MAMP called [MNPP](http://getmnpp.org/). It has everything MAMP has, but updated.</s>

Edit: 7 years later the project looks to be abandoned and the main domain is gone. The repo is still around but hasn't been updated in ages, so I would not recommend using it. For reference here's the repo url:  https://github.com/jyr/MNPP

Comment: Worth noting that this runs Nginx instead of Apache -- which is fine, iff you mainly deploy to Nginx servers...

Comment: Does it make such a big difference for PHP development?

Comment: If you're writing all new code using a framework or somesuch, probably not. However, moderns CMSes like Drupal and WordPress need a bit of cajoling to work with Nginx, which is a pain if you're ultimately deploying to an Apache-based stack in the end anyway.

Comment: To clear up any misconceptions for future readers, I disagree with you @aendrew, if you're deploying from an NGINX server locally to Apache live the only concern you should have is your .htaccess file, if it's even used. As you say yourself but contort, the issue is configuring Nginx to work with Drupal/Wordpress. You're configuring the SERVER. Once the code is developed and goes up to Apache, Apache is blind to what you've done to the server. So I don't understand your point on it being a pain, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @MattWithoos I wrote that after spending a lot of time trying to get nginx+php5-fpm+Drupal7 working, and I seem to remember doing a fair bit of configuration on the D7-side (particularly with things like friendly URLs, image handling). That said, that was ages ago and I might be wrong, and it might all be a lot easier now. TBH, there's something to be said for deploying to an environment similar to your development environment — although I will admit I now develop WP stuff locally using Nginx via https://www.npmjs.org/package/sng.

Comment: On your point about something to be said about the local environment and live environment being the same, certainly. However, currently I'm working with an organisation to build a distributed app, which means it's on a variety of server environments; so the case for using the same local/live server is less important to me in this case. You aren't wrong, though, Drupal can be tricky to get working on Nginx in a safe, secure way.

Comment: The MNPP website seems to be offline.

Comment: Yeah that was 2013 - it looks like the project is dead now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure XAMPP works on the mac. But it's not as good as MAMP.

Comment: -1 He's looking for something *better* than MAMP.

Comment: No, he's looking for something *CHEAPER* than MAMP Pro. Since I don't know his full needs, I provided a possibility, though, I agree, I wouldn't really recommend it.

Comment: Sorry, I meant MAMP, not MAMP *Pro*. I think you were referring to MAMP Pro in your post but I read it has plain MAMP. If that's the case, then edit your post and I'll remove my down vote.